# Need to refer child objects records also in PDF

Tags: soql, class, dynamic-soql, apex, wrapper-class

I have a requirement to display child object records also alongwith Parent records. Please find the below SOQL pattern.

```
SELECT Name, Account_Abs_abv__c,Account_Location_abv__c,Attendee_Role_abv__c ,City_abv__c,Zip_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name,Account_Name_abv__c ,Address_Line2_abv__c,id,Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c , Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c , Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c , Outcome_abv__c , RecordType.Name, 
(select Call_Detail_abv__r.Product_vod__r.Name,
Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__r.Name,
Call_Sample_abv__r.Quantity_vod__c from Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__r),
Prof_First_Name_abv__c,Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c,Prof_Last_Name_abv__c,Address_Line1_abv__c,
Call_abv__r.Territory_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.account_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.account_vod__r.Name,
Call_abv__r.account_vod__r.Abbott_Best_Specialty_ABT__c,
Call_abv__r.Address_Line_1_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.Address_Line_2_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.City_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.State_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.Zip_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.Call_Date_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.Professional_First_Name_ABT__c,
Call_abv__r.Professional_Last_Name_ABT__c,
Call_abv__r.Professional_Middle_Name_ABT__c,
Call_abv__r.Attendee_Role_CIA__c  ,
Call_abv__r.Professional_Type_ABT__c,
Call_abv__r.Professional_Abbott_Best_Specialty_ABT__c,
Call_abv__r.Attendee_Associated_Prescriber_CIA__c.Name,
Call_abv__r.Attendee_Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c,
Call_abv__r.RecordType.Name ,
Call_abv__r.Call_Type_vod__c,
Call_abv__r.Call_Datetime_vod__c
FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c
```

I have below apex class. Can someone incorporate the change here please?

```
public class IncidentDetailExtnController_NEW{
    public Incident_abv__c oInc {get;set;}
    public Boolean Done{get;set;}
    Id recId;
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> oIncTranListHCPDetail {get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> oIncTranListHCI {get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> oIncTranListPharmacy{get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>oIncTranListHCPSamples{get;set;}
    public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>oIncTranListHCPSpeaker{get;set;}
        public List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c>oIncTranListSynch{get;set;}
    public String profName{get;set;}
    public Map<id,String> MapIncTxn{get;set;}
        public Boolean k{get;set;}

        public String subject { get; set; }
    public String body { get; set; }

    public IncidentDetailExtnController_NEW(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {
        Done = false;
        recId =ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('Id');
        oInc = (Incident_abv__c) controller.getRecord();
        /*oIncTranListHCPDetail = [SELECT Account_Abs_abv__c,Account_Location_abv__c,Attendee_Role_abv__c ,City_abv__c,Zip_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name,Account_Name_abv__c ,
                                Call_Detail_abv__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Product_vod__c ,Address_Line2_abv__c, Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , State_abv__c,
                                Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call_Detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Address_vod__c , Call_Detail_abv__r.Type_vod__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Activity_Type__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Address_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , id,
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call_Sample_abv__r.Quantity_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__c , Call_Sample_abv__r.Product_vod__r.Product_Type_vod__c , 
                                Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c , Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c , Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c , Outcome_abv__c , RecordType.Name , Call__c , 
                                Call__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call__r.Address_vod__c, Call__r.Detailed_Products_vod__c,Prof_First_Name_abv__c,Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c,Prof_Last_Name_abv__c,Address_Line1_abv__c
                                 FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and RecordType.Name in ('HCP Calls')];
                 */
                     oIncTranListHCPDetail = [SELECT Name, Account_Abs_abv__c,Account_Location_abv__c,Attendee_Role_abv__c ,City_abv__c,Zip_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name,Account_Name_abv__c ,
                                Address_Line2_abv__c,   id,                                 
                                Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c , Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c , Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c , Outcome_abv__c , RecordType.Name , /*Call__c , 
                                Call__r.Account_vod__r.Name , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_ABS_CIA__c , Call__r.Associated_Prescriber_CIA__r.Name , Call__r.Call_Date_vod__c , 
                                Call__r.Address_vod__c, Call__r.Detailed_Products_vod__c, */
                                Prof_First_Name_abv__c,Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c,Prof_Last_Name_abv__c,Address_Line1_abv__c
                                 FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
                                 RecordType.Name in ('HCP Calls')];

              oIncTranListHCI = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c
            ,City_abv__c ,Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where RecordType.Name in ('HIC/HCO Calls') and Incident_abv__c = :recId];
            //Type =Pharmacy
            oIncTranListPharmacy= [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c, Account_Location_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Pharmacy Calls')];

            oIncTranListHCPSamples = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c, Account_Location_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Samples')];

            oIncTranListHCPSpeaker = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Speaker Program Attendees')];

            oIncTranListSynch = [SELECT ABBT_Customer_Id_abv__c, Account_Abs_abv__c,Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__r.Name, Account_Location_abv__c, Account_Name_abv__c, Associated_Account_Name_abv__c, 
            Associated_HCP_Name_abv__c, Associated_Prescriber_ID_abv__c, Attendee_Role_abv__c,   CreatedById, CreatedDate, Date_of_Last_Sync_abv__c, Date_of_Prev_Sync_abv__c, Days_bwn_Sync_abv__c, IsDeleted, Event_Location_abv__c, Event_Topic_abv__c, Incident_abv__c, 
            Inc_Transaction_ID_abv__c, Name, IsLocked, LastActivityDate, LastModifiedById, LastModifiedDate, MayEdit, Medical_Event_abv__c, Outcome_abv__c, Outcome_Date_abv__c, Outcome_Selected_By_User_Name_abv__c, Outcome_selected_By_User_ID_abv__c, Prof_Abs_abv__c, Address_Line1_abv__c, Address_Line2_abv__c, City_abv__c, Prof_Designation_abv__c, Prof_First_Name_abv__c, Prof_Last_Name_abv__c, Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c, State_abv__c, Zip_abv__c, Id, SystemModstamp, Transaction_Date_abv__c, RecordType.Name 
            FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c where Incident_abv__c = :recId and 
            RecordType.Name in ('Synch Rate report')];



   Map<id,String> MapIncTxn= new Map<id,String>();   

   for(   Incident_Transaction_abv__c IT :oIncTranListHCPDetail )
   {
   profName=IT.Prof_First_Name_abv__c+' '+IT.Prof_Middle_Name_abv__c+' '+IT.Prof_Last_Name_abv__c;
   MapIncTxn.put(IT.id,profName);

   }
  //  PageReference p = send();                            

    }   //constr ends  
    public PageReference attest()
    {

        return null;
    }   

    public PageReference send() {
        String addresses;
        boolean mssg;
        // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 


        // Reference the attachment page and pass in the account ID
        PageReference pdf = Page.VF_IncidentDetail_PDF3;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)recId); //
        pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

        // Take the PDF content
        try
        {
            Blob b = pdf.getContent();
            String UserEmail = [Select Email from User where Id=:UserInfo.getUserId() limit 1].Email;

            Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
            String IncName = [Select Name from Incident_abv__c where Id=:oInc.Id limit 1].Name;
            efa.setFileName('IncidentReport_' + IncName + '.pdf');
            efa.setBody(b); 

            addresses = UserEmail + ':'  + 'anilkumar.lingaraju@abbvie.com'+':'+'tumpu1985@gmail.com'+':'+'saikat.neogy@cognizant.com' ;
            String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);

            // Sets the paramaters of the email
            email.setSubject('Incident Report for ' + IncName);
            email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
            body = 'Hi ' + UserInfo.getName() + '\n\n Please find attached the report requested by you.\n\n Regards \n IrepTeam'  ;
            email.setPlainTextBody( body );

            email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});        // Sends the email
            Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   
            Done = true;
            ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Your Email has been successfully Sent'));
        }

        catch(Exception x)
        {
             ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR, 'Exception:' + x.getMessage()));
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from adding the child record part to the query you do not necessarily have to change anything else in the controller. In the Visualforce you can reference the line item collection of each incident like this:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!oIncTranListHCPDetail}" var ="incident">
    <apex:outputText value="{!incident.Name}"/>
    ...
    <apex:repeat value="{!incident.Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__r}" var="line">
        <apex:outputText value="{!line.Call_Detail_abv__r.Product_vod__r.Name}"/>
        ...
    </apex:repeat>
    ...
</apex:repeat>
```